# How can I set up different startup profiles?

Tags: grub2, services, users, .profile

I'm fairly sure this is a basic question, nevertheless I'm having some problems with solving this.

I'm trying to set up different startup profiles set specifically to different activities... like when I want to do web development and such, it would start the Apache server and other stuff, but when I'm not these services would be disabled - once I get the logic of it, I can tailor it, hope you get the picture as to what I'd like to do.

My first thought was that it would be selected in Grub, but if anyone has a different suggestion, don't hold it in. :)

Thanks,
Din

Comment: By "startup" do you mean "boot" or "login"?

Comment: Both, basically. I don't really care either way as long as it works :) I'm working on a netbook, which doesn't exactly fly from power ( :P ), so I don't want unnecessary services running... I want to set up some profiles, so when I test web design on localhost, I can have Apache, MySQL and the rest running, but when I play games, all those turned off so I can squeeze all the power out of this thing. I could do it manually, or I can even make a script for it, but if there would be an easier way... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to create multiple accounts with activity as real name and then you link them together with symlinks and you can put a script in "Startup Application" to have the services started you want.

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner way to do this would be to use runlevels.

Each runlevel starts a different set of services. While you could simply use a script at logon, you could create a specific runlevel for casual use, server use, etc.

The tool Ubuntu uses to configure what services start with each runlevel is called Upstart. A simple tool 'chkconfig', installable from the Ubuntu main repositories, will help you set those up.

```
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
```

Once you have configured each runlevel, you are going to have to start it. I think the cleanest way to do that would be from GRUB.

Create a different entry for each runlevel (copy & paste current kernel startup section to create a new entry), then find the line like: 'linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-14-generic root=UUID=1459c642-797c-4a9b-be5c-fdfad2a6689c ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7' and add the number of the runlevel you want to boot into at the end.

Example: linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-14-generic root=UUID=1459c642-797c-4a9b-be5
c-fdfad2a6689c ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7 **3**

To check the runlevel after boot:

```
who -r
```

Below are some links to start you off:

[Basics of runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel)

[Advanced: Auto-Config of GRUB](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137221) - so you don't have to manually edit the GRUB file with each kernel release

[Using Upstart and Chkconfig](https://superuser.com/questions/266040/how-do-you-disable-an-upstart-service-in-ubuntu-10-10)